# How to reference angular controllers through different directories

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

Okay, here goes.  I started learning my first node.js/MEAN application last night, and found this tutorial to get me started with the basics:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular

So I went through that and got the app up and running pretty easily and I figured for the next step I'd try and break things out into a more modular structure.  So this is what I was going for:

```
-app
--controllers
---core.js
--models
---todo.js
--views
---index.html
-public
-routes
--todo.js
models.js
package.json
routes.js
server.js
```

So I pretty much got everything working with this structure at this point but the one thing I can't get working right is index.html doesn't work with core.js anymore.  So in the index file I used to have:

```
<script src="core.js"></script>
```

And I updated that to be:

```
<script src="../controllers/core.js"></script>
```

to work with the new structure. For some reason that breaks the app and it doesn't load core.js properly anymore. But if I put them into the same directory again and revert the src on the script tag it works again.  That's the only thing keeping me from finishing.  Any insights or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it looks that you have incorrect http server config. How are you serving static files?

Comment: The `index.html` belongs in the root folder. Other views for other pages and templates go into `views`. When you go to your website's (or any website's) URL it takes the index file from the root folder, which for you I assume is defined as the parent of `app`. You can set the server to serve from `app/views` but that wouldn't be the right structure.

Comment: @lujcon I updated my server config to have `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));` and it seems like that may have fixed it.  Thanks for the static files tip.

Comment: @Mosho Thanks for the heads up.  I'll do some reading and look into moving that index to the root of the project.

Comment: @gspeager please don't. It doesn't matter where index is placed on your hard drive. Just arange your files as you want. What's important - don't mix sever and client files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my server config to have `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));` and it seems like that fixed it